Is it impossible to show the battery percent in the Windows statusbar?
In the Windows status bar there is a battery indicator. Is it impossible to show the battery percent in the status bar? I've searched the Windows Settings.

Though it seems like it would be an obviously desirable feature, there is no native way is keep that percentage displayed. sigh
